# Allow-IAP Firewall Rule created in default VPC in GCP getting reflected in other VPC as well

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-vpc, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I have a below firewall rule created in default VPC. It is configured to be applicable to all the instances in the VPC.

[image: Firewall Rule to allow-ingress-from-iap in default VPC]

Now, If I remove "all" from ports, I start getting below warning for all the VMs in IAP console.
which is okay as per the reference below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62635234/10580233

[image: IAP warning when firewall rule has only 22 and 3389 port mentioned]

**the issue is** , when I configure "all" for firewall in default VPC even the warning for VMs which are outside in default VPC is getting disappeared. Are the IAP firewall rules are applied across the projects, which I do not think so. I have allow-ingress-from-iap firewall rule configured in other VPC as well but it is with only 22 and 3389 ports so ideally IAP should show warning for them.

[image: allow-iap rule for default and customized vpc]

Answer (score 0):

allow tcp 22 port for ssh protocol in firewall rule.